# How to make helper variable visible to 2nd view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two very related models in my application, and I have a helper method defined that iterates through all relevant parameters in Model A, stores the correct parameters into an array called "appParams" in the helper method, and now I'd like to create a new instance of Model B based solely on those 'appParams'.

**Helper method:**

```
module AppsHelper
    def gen_application(template)
        template=ApplicationTemplate.find(template.id)
        appParams=[]
        template.attributes.each do |name, value|
            if value == true
                appParams << name.to_s
            end
        end
        appParams.map {|i| i.to_sym}
        @appParams=appParams
    end
end
```

My problem is how to make that @appParams variable visible to Model B's view?  Right now if I display the value of @appParams on Model A's `show` view, the value of @appParams shows up.  But if I make that same call on Model B's `new` view, the value of @appParams is blank.

Essentially the problem is how can I make that variable visible to multiple controllers and views?

**This works: (/views/model_a/show.html.erb)**

```
`<ul><li><%= gen_application(@template) %></li></ul>`
```

---

**This does not work [@appParams shows up blank]: (/views/model_b/new.html.erb)**

```
`<ul><li><%= @appParams %></li></ul>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, I doubt you really need global variables in your app (especially in this case). But here's a solution for this:

Put your method `gen_application(template)` in your ApplicationController (common to all controllers) or in a module which you will include in both controllers. Then, if you need this variable in the action **new** of controller **Dragon** you can call it directly since it inherits ApplicationController (or the module). Though, if you need it in action **show** of controller **Rabbit** you can also call it. If you want it before every action in your controller, call it in a **before_filter** callback in your ApplicationController.

Comment: Thanks Tiago.  I'm definitely not a fan of global variables in any case, but I guess my question was due to the fact that I didn't know how to transfer a variable from one model/controller to another without using a global helper